# Vim still displays the last removed character

Tags: encoding

when my terminal `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, my vim display is messed in that when page down or page up, the last page's conent is still displayed. or when I delete a character, for example, in "abcdef", I use `x` to delete character "a", the display in vim is "bcdeff", even though there is no actual 'f' at the end. I added `set encoding=utf8` in .vimrc and it doesn't help. How to make vim working with terminal of locale setting like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Which O.S. are you on? What terminal emulator are you using? What's the value of the $TERM variable in your shell? Please add more details that would help guess what's going on here.

Comment: also try with a minimal vimrc first, so first test if this also happens with `vim --clean`

Comment: Does this _only_ happen with that locale setup?